# How to get flash messages working with handlebars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, connect-flash

I am trying to get flash working with my handlebars templates, but it doesn't work. How can I display messages

> if (!user) return done(null, false, { message: 'No user found'})

and

> return done(null, false, { message: 'Oops! Wrong password.'})

in the alert box?

*Installed packages: express, connect-flash, express-handlebars, passport, passport-local, express-session, connect-mongo*

```
app.use(flash())

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return done(err)
      if (!user) return done(null, false, { message: 'No user found'})
        user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, user)
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Oops! Wrong password.'})
          }
        })
    })
}))

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}))
```

**Handlebars template:**

```
{{#if message}}
<div class="alert alert-danger">{{message}}</div>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.locals.message = req.flash('message');
    res.render('login');
});
```